# Mostrar marcador en Google Maps Api Js (Solo si esta dentro del radio circle)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Necesito mostrar marcadores en un mapa, solamente si están dentro del radio del circulo mostrado en la pantalla. Pero no se, como validar si efectivamente el marcador esta o no esta dentro del radio.

```js
var myLatLng = { lat: 14.151171, lng: -90.841083 };
var myLatLng2 = { lat: 14.15009000, lng: -90.84334708 };

function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeId: 'terrain',
      zoom: 18
    });
  
    var markerYesShow = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Yes Show Into Radio'
    });
    
    var markerNotShow = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng2,
      map: map,
      title: 'Not Show '
    });
  
    var alerta = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: myLatLng,
      radius: 100
    });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
 <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js??key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un círculo con centro en las coordenadas X1,Y1 y radio R. Lo que necesitas es comprobar que el punto (X,Y) se encuentra a una distancia de (X1,Y1) menor al valor de R:

```js
let ejeX=10,ejeY=10;
let radio=5;

function dentroDelCirculo(x,y) {
 return ((ejeX-x)**2 + (ejeY-y)**2) <= radio**2;
}

console.log('dentro?:' + dentroDelCirculo(14,10));
console.log('dentro?:' + dentroDelCirculo(75,35));
```

Nota: `**` es la notación de potencias en JS, pero en un navegador antiguo quizá no funcione, por lo que puedes multiplicar por sí mismo cada valor o usar `Math.pow` para hacer la operación.